Second photo is not displaying
I am doing a fitness app in flutter and I try to make an ui where the user adds their diet, the problem is when I upload first photo it worked of the breakfast but when I try lunch it didn't work out. Here is a video of the issue https://imgur.com/a/vYUj6b6 and here is a photo of the terminal:

This is the code
 class FoodDietContent extends StatefulWidget {
  final String programId;
  final String dietProgramId;

  FoodDietContent({required this.programId, required this.dietProgramId});

  @override
  _FoodDietContentState createState() => _FoodDietContentState();
}

class _FoodDietContentState extends State<FoodDietContent> {
  File? _image;
  final picker = ImagePicker();

  Future<String> _loadDietProgramTitle() async {
    try {
      final doc = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('programs')
          .doc(widget.programId)
          .collection('diet_programs')
          .doc(widget.dietProgramId)
          .get();

      if (doc.exists) {
        return '${doc['week']} ${doc['day']}';
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error loading diet program title: $e');
    }
    return 'Unknown';
  }

  Stream<QuerySnapshot> _getMeals() {
    print('Getting meals for program: ${widget.programId}, diet program: ${widget.dietProgramId}');
    return FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('programs')
        .doc(widget.programId)
        .collection('diet_programs')
        .doc(widget.dietProgramId)
        .collection('meals')
        .snapshots()
        .map((snapshot) {
          print('Received ${snapshot.docs.length} meals');
          snapshot.docs.forEach((doc) {
            print('Meal: ${doc.data()}');
          });
          return snapshot;
        });
  }

  void _addDietContent() {
    String? selectedTime;
    final mealNameController = TextEditingController();
    final mealDescriptionController = TextEditingController();
    final caloriesController = TextEditingController();
    File? tempImage;

    showModalBottomSheet(
      context: context,
      isScrollControlled: true,
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(top: Radius.circular(20)),
      ),
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return StatefulBuilder(
          builder: (BuildContext context, StateSetter setState) {
            return SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                color: Colors.white,
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      'Add New Meal',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 24,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        color: Colors.black,
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 20),
                    Text(
                      'Choose the time of the day',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 18,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                        color: Colors.black87,
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 15),
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                      children: [
                        _buildMealTimeButton('Breakfast', Icons.free_breakfast, selectedTime, (value) {
                          setState(() => selectedTime = value);
                        }),
                        _buildMealTimeButton('Lunch', Icons.lunch_dining, selectedTime, (value) {
                          setState(() => selectedTime = value);
                        }),
                        _buildMealTimeButton('Dinner', Icons.dinner_dining, selectedTime, (value) {
                          setState(() => selectedTime = value);
                        }),
                      ],
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 20),
                    TextField(
                      controller: mealNameController,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        hintText: 'Enter meal\'s name',
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                          borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey[300]!),
                        ),
                        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                          borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.black, width: 2),
                        ),
                        filled: true,
                        fillColor: Colors.grey[50],
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 15),
                    TextField(
                      controller: mealDescriptionController,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        hintText: 'Meal description',
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                          borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey[300]!),
                        ),
                        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                          borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.black, width: 2),
                        ),
                        filled: true,
                        fillColor: Colors.grey[50],
                      ),
                      maxLines: 3,
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 15),
                    TextField(
                      controller: caloriesController,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        hintText: 'Total number of calories',
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                          borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey[300]!),
                        ),
                        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                          borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.black, width: 2),
                        ),
                        filled: true,
                        fillColor: Colors.grey[50],
                      ),
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 20),
                    ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () async {
                        final pickedFile = await picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
                        if (pickedFile != null) {
                          setState(() {
                            tempImage = File(pickedFile.path);
                          });
                          print('Image selected: ${pickedFile.path}');
                        } else {
                          print('No image selected');
                        }
                      },
                      child: Text('Add photo of the meal'),
                      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                        foregroundColor: Colors.black,
                        elevation: 5,
                        shadowColor: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5),
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                        ),
                        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15, horizontal: 40),
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 20),
                    if (tempImage != null)
                      Container(
                        width: 100,
                        height: 100,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          image: DecorationImage(
                            image: FileImage(tempImage!),
                            fit: BoxFit.cover,
                          ),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                        ),
                      ),
                    SizedBox(height: 20),
                    ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () async {
                        if (selectedTime != null && 
                            mealNameController.text.isNotEmpty &&
                            caloriesController.text.isNotEmpty) {
                          String? imageUrl;
                          if (tempImage != null) {
                            print('Attempting to upload image...');
                            imageUrl = await _uploadImage(tempImage!);
                            print('Image upload result: $imageUrl');
                          } else {
                            print('No image selected');
                          }
                          await _saveMeal(
                            selectedTime!,
                            mealNameController.text,
                            mealDescriptionController.text,
                            int.parse(caloriesController.text),
                            imageUrl,
                          );
                          Navigator.pop(context);
                        } else {
                          print('Invalid input: Time: $selectedTime, Name: ${mealNameController.text}, Calories: ${caloriesController.text}');
                          ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                            SnackBar(content: Text('Please fill all required fields')),
                          );
                        }
                      },
                      child: Text('Add Meal'),
                      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
                        foregroundColor: Colors.white,
                        minimumSize: Size(double.infinity, 50),
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            );
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }

  Widget _buildMealTimeButton(String title, IconData icon, String? selectedTime, Function(String) onSelect) {
    bool isSelected = selectedTime == title;
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () => onSelect(title),
      child: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10, horizontal: 15),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: isSelected ? Colors.black : Colors.grey[200],
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
        ),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Icon(
              icon,
              color: isSelected ? Colors.white : Colors.black,
              size: 30,
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 5),
            Text(
              title,
              style: TextStyle(
                color: isSelected ? Colors.white : Colors.black,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<String?> _uploadImage(File image) async {
    try {
      print('Starting image upload...');
      final ref = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child('meal_images/${DateTime.now().toIso8601String()}.jpg');
      print('Created storage reference');
      
      final metadata = SettableMetadata(contentType: 'image/jpeg');
      print('Created metadata');
      
      final uploadTask = ref.putFile(image, metadata);
      print('Started upload task');
      
      uploadTask.snapshotEvents.listen((TaskSnapshot snapshot) {
        print('Upload progress: ${snapshot.bytesTransferred}/${snapshot.totalBytes}');
      });

      final snapshot = await uploadTask.whenComplete(() => print('Upload completed'));
      print('Upload task completed');
      
      final downloadUrl = await snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
      print('Got download URL: $downloadUrl');
      
      return downloadUrl;
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error uploading image: $e');
      return null;
    }
  }

  Future<void> _saveMeal(String time, String name, String description, int calories, String? imageUrl) async {
    try {
      final mealData = {
        'time': time,
        'name': name,
        'description': description,
        'calories': calories,
        'imageUrl': imageUrl,
      };
      print('Attempting to save meal data: $mealData');
      await FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('programs')
          .doc(widget.programId)
          .collection('diet_programs')
          .doc(widget.dietProgramId)
          .collection('meals')
          .add(mealData);
      print('Meal saved successfully');
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        SnackBar(content: Text('Meal added successfully')),
      );
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error saving meal: $e');
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        SnackBar(content: Text('Failed to add meal: $e')),
      );
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            // Add this new row for the back button
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, top: 20),
              child: IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back, color: Colors.black),
                onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
              ),
            ),
            FutureBuilder<String>(
              future: _loadDietProgramTitle(),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                  return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                  return Center(child: Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}'));
                } else {
                  return Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                    child: Text(
                      snapshot.data ?? 'Unknown',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 24,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        color: Colors.black,
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                }
              },
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
                stream: _getMeals(),
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                    return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                  } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                    return Center(child: Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}'));
                  } else if (!snapshot.hasData || snapshot.data!.docs.isEmpty) {
                    return Center(child: Text('No meals added yet.'));
                  } else {
                    return ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        var meal = snapshot.data!.docs[index];
                        return _buildSwipeableMealCard(meal);
                      },
                    );
                  }
                },
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _addDietContent,
        child: Icon(Icons.add, color: Colors.white),
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      ),
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerFloat,
    );
  }

  Widget _buildSwipeableMealCard(DocumentSnapshot meal) {
    return Dismissible(
      key: Key(meal.id),
      direction: DismissDirection.endToStart,
      background: Container(
        alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 20.0),
        color: Colors.red,
        child: Icon(Icons.delete, color: Colors.white),
      ),
      onDismissed: (direction) {
        _deleteMeal(meal.id);
      },
      child: _buildMealCard(meal),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildMealCard(DocumentSnapshot meal) {
    final mealData = meal.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
    print('Building meal card for: ${mealData['name']}');
    print('Image URL: ${mealData['imageUrl']}');

    return Card(
      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16, vertical: 8),
      color: Colors.white,
      elevation: 4,
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
      ),
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.white,
        child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
          child: Row(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              _buildMealImage(mealData),
              SizedBox(width: 16),
              Expanded(
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        mealData['time'] ?? 'No time',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          fontSize: 18,
                          color: Colors.black87,
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 4),
                      Text(
                        mealData['name'] ?? 'No name',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          fontSize: 16,
                          color: Colors.black,
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 8),
                      Row(
                        children: [
                          Icon(Icons.local_fire_department, size: 16, color: Colors.orange),
                          SizedBox(width: 4),
                          Text(
                            '${mealData['calories'] ?? 'No'} calories',
                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14, color: Colors.grey[600]),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 8),
                      Text(
                        mealData['description'] ?? 'No description',
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14, color: Colors.grey[800]),
                        maxLines: 2,
                        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildMealImage(Map<String, dynamic> mealData) {
    return Container(
      width: 80,
      height: 80,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.white,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
        boxShadow: [
          BoxShadow(
            color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.3),
            spreadRadius: 1,
            blurRadius: 3,
            offset: Offset(0, 1),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      child: ClipRRect(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
        child: mealData['imageUrl'] != null
            ? Image.network(
                mealData['imageUrl'],
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                errorBuilder: (context, error, stackTrace) {
                  print('Error loading image: $error');
                  return Container(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    child: Icon(Icons.error, size: 40, color: Colors.red[300]),
                  );
                },
              )
            : Container(
                color: Colors.grey[100],
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Icon(Icons.restaurant_menu, size: 40, color: Colors.grey[400]),
                    Text('No Image', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey[400], fontSize: 10)),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _deleteMeal(String mealId) {
    FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('programs')
        .doc(widget.programId)
        .collection('diet_programs')
        .doc(widget.dietProgramId)
        .collection('meals')
        .doc(mealId)
        .delete()
        .then((_) {
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        SnackBar(content: Text('Meal deleted successfully')),
      );
    }).catchError((error) {
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        SnackBar(content: Text('Failed to delete meal: $error')),
      );
    });
  }
}


FYI: In general only add any kind of text as text not as images. You can format it with the quote/code blocks if you like.
